# Virt-manager -- USB device visibility on host and in Linux VM, but not in Windows VM

Tags: usb, qemu, libvirt

I have an FTDI device connected to my host *(machine that runs hypervisor i.e. `virt-manager`/`qemu`)*.

---

**Host** sees the device just fine:

```
ziga@ziga--hypervisor:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 0403:6010 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT2232C/D/H Dual UART/FIFO IC
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
ziga@ziga--hypervisor:~$
```

---

Now the VMs:

- I double click my **Linux VM** so that it opens up *(it doesn't start yet)*.
- I follow the <kbd>View</kbd><kbd>Details</kbd> in the main menu.
- I click <kbd>Add Hardware</kbd> and select <kbd>USB Host Device</kbd> from the list.
- I choose an entry `001:008 Future Technology Devices International, Ltd FT2232C/D/H Dual UART/FIFO IC` and click <kbd>Finish</kbd>.

Now I start the **Linux VM** and it can normally see the USB device. I then turn off the **Linux VM** and remove this device from it.

Now I repeat the procedure of adding the USB device to the **Windows VM** in the exact same manner, but after I run **Windows VM** it does not see the device.

---

All VM's `.qcow2` files are owned by `libvirt-qemu:libvirt-qemu`.

---

What am I missing on the Windows VM in order so that it can see the device?

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with USB2 vs USB3? Then it could be guest (and their driver) dependent. I had a similar problem connecting a device in the past. Perhaps try a different physical port? I assume the QEMU XML config file has the same virtual model of USB emulation?

Comment: Shouldn't I first see the device under "Computer Management/Device Manager" where there is a section "Ports (COM & LPT)"? It is not there... Shouldnt it show up there even without drivers?

Comment: This is an FTDI chip i.e. FT2232H and it uses FTDI D2XX drivers: https://ftdichip.com/drivers/d2xx-drivers/ I installed those but nothing changes. Even after rebooting the Windows VM.

Comment: @Ned64 I tried changing USB driver from "USB3" to "USB2" but symptoms are the same.

Comment: I believe the physical chip does not matter - as a virtualised device I would assume that the OS-internal drivers need to match Qemu's emulation rather than the physical chip. Please confirm that the QEMU XML file has the same entries for USB emulation for the Windows+Linux VMs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with my ***Aeotec Z-Wave USB Z-Stick*** and was resolved by changing the physical USB port. I don't believe USB2 or USB3 matters, but definately using a different physical port helps.